# RHEL8: Does NFS I/O count as part of "%iowait" calculations?

Tags: performance, nfs, iowait, rhel8

Customer telling us that they see high %iowait in top and iostat output on a busy RHEL8 NFS client.

iostat man page clearly says that iowait is related to % of time kernel is waiting on "disk" I/O

Question - does NFS I/O count as "disk" I/O in %iowait calculations?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on Linux, NFS is included in iowait time, and contributes to the load average.

[Red Hat KB Does NFS cient I/O count iowait% on linux?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2567931) shows packet loss to an NFS server increasing iowait. Eventually your NFS server may go away unexpectedly, try looking at iostat in that bad state.

Tasks that sleep on I/O contribute to these iowait metrics in process accounting.  [NFS does this, it calls io_schedule().](https://medium.com/ticketmaster-tech/does-nfs-i-o-count-towards-iowait-on-linux-7990b3bbe634)

"Disk" is a shorthand for processes waiting on I/O, which typically but not always are block devices.